# Transitive dependency with a bom

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-bom

I have a project named P1 which is a spring-boot project.
The pom has already a parent pom, so I decided to use springboot with a bom.

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

This project is then deployed as P1.jar

Then I have a 2nd project named P2.
This project has only 1 dependecy which is the P1 project :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>p1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is an extract of mvn dependency:tree for both project :

P1:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
```

P2:

```
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.9.RELEASE:compile
```

As you can see, the spring-orm dependency differs.
Can someone explains me how this works and how can I fix that ?

At the moment I added the BOM in my 2nd project. But it's not my goal.
I want to be able to import P1 project with its REAL dependencies without having to do anything else or know which bom the project is using.

Comment: There should be some other dependency in P2 that is causing, can you paste full poms of P1and P2 here to solve the issue

Comment: The P2 project is really empty ... Only one dependency to P1.
Looks like that when I'm using a bom in P1, the transitive dependencies from dependencies I add are using the version declared in bom.
But when using P1 as a dependency, the transitive of declared dependencies are the minimum version in maven central.